# GRASS v.qcount in QGIS is returning insanely high counts

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I'm trying to use GRASS's [v.qcount](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.qcount.html) command through the QGIS processing toolbox to conduct a simple quadrat point pattern analysis. I've run the tool on some projected point data, but I keep getting crazy results. Looking at the attribute table of the generated quadrats layer, I can see that a few have accurate counts of the contained points e.g. 0,3,7,5 and then a couple others have counts with numbers like 1937006962 and 1768910880 which are orders of magnitude higher than the number of points in the input dataset.

Below is the log:

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'v.qcount' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'input' : '/tmp/processing_b80793a2bb9b479380511b0bdebcb473/5a614c1889ba4511a045e094cac490bb/output.shp', 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'output' : '/tmp/processing_b80793a2bb9b479380511b0bdebcb473/c1b49479700b42b6a67a3244dce54623/output.shp', 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'nquadrats' : 10, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'radius' : 100 }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="/tmp/processing_b80793a2bb9b479380511b0bdebcb473/5a614c1889ba4511a045e094cac490bb/output.shp" output="vector_5bae70fe08c63598" --overwrite -o
g.region n=4345228.065848096 s=4340221.034201001 e=707205.6885515669 w=703307.6682009684
v.qcount input=vector_5bae70fe08c63598 nquadrats=10 radius=100 output=outputb490bc6f27ac441e9cde3a3cd9a0cbc1 --overwrite
v.out.ogr -c type="auto" input="outputb490bc6f27ac441e9cde3a3cd9a0cbc1" output="/tmp/processing_b80793a2bb9b479380511b0bdebcb473/c1b49479700b42b6a67a3244dce54623/output.shp" format="ESRI_Shapefile" --overwrite
Cleaning up temporary files...

Starting GRASS GIS...

Executing </tmp/processing_b80793a2bb9b479380511b0bdebcb473/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> ...

Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default

Projection information updated

Over-riding projection check

Check if OGR layer <output> contains polygons...

0..10..20..30..40..50..60..70..80..90..100

Creating attribute table for layer <output>...

Column name <cat> renamed to <cat_>

Importing 10 features (OGR layer <output>)...

0..10..20..30..40..50..60..70..80..90..100

-----------------------------------------------------

Building topology for vector map <vector_5bae70fe08c63598@PERMANENT>...

Registering primitives...



10 primitives registered

10 vertices registered

Building areas...

0..10..20..30..40..50..60..70..80..90..100

0 areas built

0 isles built

Attaching islands...

Attaching centroids...

10..20..30..40..50..60..70..80..90..100

Number of nodes: 0

Number of primitives: 10

Number of points: 10

Number of lines: 0

Number of boundaries: 0

Number of centroids: 0

Number of areas: 0

Number of isles: 0

Finding quadrats...

10..20..30..40..50..60..70..80..90..Counting points quadrats...

Building topology for vector map <outputb490bc6f27ac441e9cde3a3cd9a0cbc1@PERMANENT>...

Registering primitives...



10 primitives registered

10 vertices registered

Building areas...

0..10..20..30..40..50..60..70..80..90..100

0 areas built

0 isles built

Attaching islands...

Attaching centroids...

10..20..30..40..50..60..70..80..90..100

Number of nodes: 0

Number of primitives: 10

Number of points: 10

Number of lines: 0

Number of boundaries: 0

Number of centroids: 0

Number of areas: 0

Number of isles: 0

-----------------------------------------------------------

Index Realization

-----------------------------------------------------------

Fisher el al (1922) Relative Variance 1.21419e+09

David & Moore (1954) Index of Cluster Size 1.21419e+09

Douglas (1975) Index of Cluster Frequency 0.489009

Lloyd (1967) "mean crowding" 1.80794e+09

Lloyd (1967) Index of patchiness 3.04495

Morisita's (1959) I (variability b/n patches) 2.84046

-----------------------------------------------------------

WARNING: No attribute table found -> using only category numbers as attributes

Exporting 10 features...

10..20..30..40..50..60..70..80..90..100

v.out.ogr complete. 10 features (Point type) written to <outputb490bc6f27ac441e9cde3a3cd9a0cbc1> (ESRI_Shapefile format).

Execution of </tmp/processing_b80793a2bb9b479380511b0bdebcb473/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> finished.

Cleaning up temporary files...

Execution completed in 1.25 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':/tmp/processing_b80793a2bb9b479380511b0bdebcb473/c1b49479700b42b6a67a3244dce54623/output.shp, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'v.qcount' finished
```

And here is some [sample data](http://natewessel.com/shared/sample-points.geojson) that gives me the error (as geojson). I also tried this with a shapefile and got the same results. Because of the warning about the attribute table I tried deleting all attributes that were there previously and replacing them with a field of all ones... no change in the output.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this tool but the line "WARNING: No attribute table found -> using only category numbers as attributes" looks suspect. Do you have a field/column with a value as well as a geometry, it looks like it's expecting one?

Comment: Can you make the data available for testing? If yes, the best way is to submit a bug report at https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ - then it reaches the developers list directly.

Comment: I've added a link to the data in the question. I'll submit a bug when I have chance, unless someone points out that I've just made a silly mistake somewhere :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the provided sample data here some tests:

```
# create a new location (project) from dataset's metadata
grass74 -c sample-points.geojson ~/grassdata/qcount_test

# import points
v.import input=sample-points.geojson output=sample_points

# check metadata
v.info sample_points

# set current region (bbox) to vector map 
g.region vector=sample_points -g

# assess geometric distances between points
v.univar -d map=sample_points -g
Calculating geometric distances between 304 primitives...
...
min=5.80536
max=7289.8
...
mean=3024.07
```

You used v.qcount with nquadrats=10 and radius=100, if that's reasonable for the given data I cannot say (not enough experience with v.qcount).

In the manual I have now highlighted, that the result is stored as category and not in an attribute table (maybe worth an enhancement ticket!).

```
v.qcount input=sample_points output=sample_points_qcount nquadrats=10 radius=100 --o
Finding quadrats...
Counting points quadrats...
Building topology for vector map <sample_points_qcount@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
10 primitives registered
10 vertices registered
Building areas...
 100%
0 areas built
0 isles built
Attaching islands...
Attaching centroids...
 100%
Number of nodes: 0
Number of primitives: 10
Number of points: 10
Number of lines: 0
Number of boundaries: 0
Number of centroids: 0
Number of areas: 0
Number of isles: 0
-----------------------------------------------------------
Index                                           Realization
-----------------------------------------------------------
Fisher el al (1922) Relative Variance            8.54769e+08
David & Moore (1954) Index of Cluster Size       8.54769e+08
Douglas (1975) Index of Cluster Frequency        1.11417
Lloyd (1967) "mean crowding"                     1.80713e+09
Lloyd (1967) Index of patchiness                 1.89753
Morisita's (1959) I (variability b/n patches)    1.80777
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Subsequently, for now use [v.category](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.category.html) and other commands able to generate statistics on the categories of the generate output map "sample_points_qcount".